# SQL- Select newest distinct combination of 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table with the following columns. These 4 rows are for 1 user.

```
| id | user_id | role_id | preference_order | updated_at          |
|----|---------|---------|------------------|---------------------|
| 83 | 45      | 7       | 1                | 2016-10-24 03:29:18 |
| 84 | 45      | 10      | 2                | 2016-10-24 03:29:18 |
| 85 | 45      | 7       | 1                | 2016-10-25 05:40:18 |
| 86 | 45      | 10      | 2                | 2016-10-25 05:40:18 |
```

What would be a *fast* way to select the *newest* distinct combination of `user_id` and `role_id` - so rows 85 and 86?

---

The closest I can get is this query, but it gets rows 83 and 84 instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_role UR
GROUP BY UR.user_id, UR.role_id
```

I also tried this, it gets 85 and 86 but it seemed too slow for a large table:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_role UR
JOIN (SELECT user_id, role_id, max(updated_at) updated_at FROM user_role GROUP BY user_id, role_id) UR2
    ON UR.user_id = UR2.user_id AND UR.role_id = UR2.role_id AND UR.updated_at = UR2.updated_at
ORDER BY UR.order ASC;
```

Comment: Could you please share the `EXPLAIN` output of your 2nd query?

Comment: Did you checked the indexes on the columns which comes in the "where" condition or "Group by"

Comment: Too slow? Fix your indexes. Create an index on (user_id, role_id, updated_at,`order`) - and don't use evil 'SELECT *'. Instead, name the columns you actually want returned. Finally, note that order is a reserved word, making it a poor choice for a table/column identifier

Comment: Please fix your tags. I doubt that you're using both MySQL and SQL-server

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM user_role
       NATURAL JOIN
       ( SELECT user_id, role_id, 
                MAX( updated_at ) AS updated_at 
           FROM user_role
          GROUP
             BY user_id, role_id ) AS t;
```

Comment: Thank you! This selected the rows I wanted :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Just wondering about the use of `SELECT DISTINCT` versus `SELECT`, in this context. It is meant to deal with duplicate rows that would have exactly the same `user_id`, `role_id` and `updated_at` timestamp? Or will it generally speed up the query? For example, assuming we are not concerned with returning duplicates as long as they agree on the selected columns, is there a reason to prefer `SELECT DISTINCT` over `SELECT`?

Comment: @sunless: A relation doesn't have duplicate tuples /by definition/. The result of a SQL query can have duplicate rows, bad news. By including the `DISTINCT` keyword I am trying to apply relational principles to SQL. I'm telling the system I never want duplicates. I trust the optimizer to know when the system actually needs to take action to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query if you need multiple user_id,role_id according to max updated_at:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id,role_id,MAX(updated_at) from user_role group by user_id,role_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, however this only returns rows for the user with the latest `updated_at`, and I have more than 1 user :(

Answer (score 0):

make use of row_number() and partition it by user_id & role_id

```
select  *
from
(
    select  *, rn = row_number () over (partition by user_id, role_id 
                                            order by updated_at desc)
    from    your_table 
) t
where   t.rn    = 1
```

Comment: If I have a billion row table will it give good performance ? I believe full table scan will happen here

Comment: make sure you have index on the `user_id, role_id, updated_at` columns

Comment: @nzguy a billion rows is a lot, so performance will likely suffer, so 'good' is relative

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
            select 
            id , user_id , role_id , ord, updated_at
            from
            (
            SELECT * ,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION  BY ID ORDER BY  pdated_at DESC ) as RID
            FROM user_role UR
            )A 
            where RID in ('1','2')
```

Answer (score 0):

order by update_at in sub query, then group by in main query.

```
select * from (
  select * from user_role order by user_id asc ,role_id asc,updated_at desc
)UR GROUP BY UR.user_id, UR.role_id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_role UR
    LEFT JOIN user_role UR2 ON UR.user_id=UR2.user_id 
                           and UR.role_id=UR2.role_id 
                           and UR.updated_at<UR2.updated_at
WHERE UR2.updated_at IS NULL
```

Comment: Where performance is the issue, this will be horrendously slow.

Comment: @Strawberry May I ask why this will be slow . If index is on `user_id, role_id, updated_at`

Comment: @NzGuy It's a reasonable question, but not one I can answer authoritatively. I know this to be so from experience. It's tragic really, because this kind of query is sometimes called a 'strawberry query' :-(  .

Comment: Thanks! I'm not too sure about performance relative to the other queries but this got the rows I wanted :)